# Does vscode support decorator after export default? How to let this enabled?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, decorator

Like on the picture below, when I write export default @Decorator class, vscode told me the syntax is wrong. How can I remove this error?

[image: error on vscode]

Update:

Yes, I know there are a lot of answer about how to enable decorator in vscode, but I really would like how to enable the decorator after the `export default`.

I just add the configuration in jsconfig.json[image: jsconfig.json]. That's not work.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding below code in config-overrides.js, for other configuration please check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_jsconfig-options

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think that's not work. I mean the decorator after `export default`, not how to enable decorator. You can see tc39's decorator [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/issues/69).

Comment: Sure, Thanks @Roger